Snowflake setting of sql variables using pyspark
I am trying to read a view in snowflake using spark.read.format("snowflake").options(**options).option("query","Set date='03-02-2018';Select *  from View123").load()
This is giving me SQL compilation error.
I understand that its because of the set date but I need it cause this View123 needs it to run.
I tried running with multiple read formats but it didn't work

Do you have the error message?

net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: SQL compilation error:

the view query is: select * from Table1 where snapshot_date=$date
